# Outputting coordinates onto a grid python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I want to take various coordinates with variables assigned to them and place them into a grid.

For example:

```
p = (0,0)
v = (2,3)
t = (5,4)
```

Would output:

```
|p| | | | | |
| | | | | | |
| | | | | | |
| | |v| | | |
| | | | | |t|
```

So obviously I could use print and go line by line but is there a way to 1. Do this more efficiently and 2. Make my grid adaptable for bigger coordinates?

Comment: I suggest you to use pandas because it's MUSH EASIER

Comment: @U8-Forward This is for an introduction to python course and they have restricted us to import os and import sys.

Comment: Ok then i will try to make a regular python solution

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach with functions that separate each of the tasks:

You first need to build a data structure that associates a name to the values so they can later be placed on the grid.
Then you must build a grid of the correct size.
Then place the labels at the place indicated by the values.
And finally assemble a representation of the grid that can be printed.

It would probably be more suitable to build a class to encapsulate the work, but maybe it is more clear, as a first step, that way.

```
def make_grid(items):
    max_col = max(x for x, _ in items) + 1
    max_row = max(y for _, y in items) + 1
    return [[' ' for dummy_col in range(max_col)] for dummy_row in range(max_row)]


def place_on_grid(grid, val, key):
    col, row = val
    grid[row][col] = key


def repr_grid(grid):
    return '\n'.join('|' + '|'.join(sub + ['']) for sub in grid)


def place_items_on_grid(data):
    grid = make_grid(data.values())
    for k, v in data.items():
        place_on_grid(grid, v, k)
    print(repr_grid(grid))


p = (0,0)
v = (2,3)
t = (5,4)
data = {k: val for k, val in zip(('p', 'v', 't'), (p, v, t))}

place_items_on_grid(data)
```

#### output:

```
|p| | | | | |
| | | | | | |
| | | | | | |
| | |v| | | |
| | | | | |t|
```